# is there a facility for generating scaffolding in a Symfony2 app?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I've been doing searches on scaffolding in Symfony 2 and keep finding references to "generators" but so far have not been able to get scaffolding up and working.

By "scaffolding" I'm referring to a way to point your tool at a database and have it generate views/forms to perform CRUD operations.

This can be useful for quickly prototyping something, and/or build a rough admin tool for some of your database tables.

It can also provide a starting point for some form you are building.

Is this possible in Symfony2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Crud operations are provided by the [SensioGeneratorBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html) which is included in the symfony standard distribution.

You can use the following command to generate form, templates & controller for existing entitites. It is interactive and can also update your routing automatically.

```
app/console generate:doctrine:crud
```

entity classes themselfes can be created with another command - interactive aswell.

```
 app/console generate:doctrine:entity
```

Generating entities from database is done with:

```
app/console doctrine:mapping:convert xml ./src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force
```

which will create xml mapping files. Afterwards you can generate entities  as follows:

```
app/console doctrine:mapping:import AcmeBlogBundle annotation
app/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeBlogBundle
```

This would generate the entities with annotations. yml and xml are supported aswell!

Answer (score 3):

You can generate entities from an existing database like [this](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html)

Then you can generate CRUD forms for those entities like [this](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_form.html)

There is no native way to create scaffolding directly from the DB. You have to go through this two step process.