# Generate RESTful web service scaffolding in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, scaffolding

I see that there is a [very useful system for generating CRUD forms from your entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695463/is-there-a-facility-for-generating-scaffolding-in-a-symfony2-app).

I'm working on a component of my app that will be a JSON service.  Is there a similar facility for generating CRUD operations that, instead of exposing an HTML form, accepts and returns JSON?  This would allow you to quickly prototype a JSON service that allows RESTful interaction with your entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695463/is-there-a-facility-for-generating-scaffolding-in-a-symfony2-app/16695918#16695918) to your other question on how to generate CRUD and simple scaffoling.

Extend [SensioGeneratorBundle](https://github.com/sensio/SensioGeneratorBundle) ( comes with the standard edition ) to generate [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle) compliant Controllers and routing to achieve what you are looking for.

The controller templates can be found in [SensioGeneratorBundle/Resources/skeleton/controller](https://github.com/sensio/SensioGeneratorBundle/tree/master/Resources/skeleton/controller).

The route templates reside in [SensioGeneratorBundle/Resources/skeleton/bundle](https://github.com/sensio/SensioGeneratorBundle/tree/master/Resources/skeleton/bundle) and are called routing.xml / .yml / ...

An example REST controller ( with automatic route generation ) can be found here: [LiipHelloBundle/Controller/ArticleController.php](https://github.com/liip/LiipHelloBundle/blob/master/Controller/ArticleController.php).

Comment: Reading through FOSRestBundle docs... Will reply if I have more questions.

Comment: This looks like it will work but will take me some time yo digest and get working. I've already got HTML CRUD forms/controllers generated, so the first thing is to try and modify one of them to be FOSRestBundle style and automatically return HTML or JSON. I was initially thinking of determining the type based on the HTTP Accept header but I think I like the route suffix idea better (I.e., .html for HTML responses, .json for JSON responses)

Comment: So, I haven't had a chance to look into this further, but what you described seems like it's the answer.  So, I'm going to mark this as the answer, and if I can get a more complete example together I'll post it here.